# cannot see particle (cocos2d-x 3.5 with Particle Designer2)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, particle-system

Development environment:
xcode 6.3
cocos2d-x 3.5
Particle Designer 2

I've create a particle in PD2, and save the project named as StarOcean.pdproject.

Following is the code:

```
auto p_StarOcean = ParticleSystemQuad::create("StarOcean.pdproject");
p_StarOcean->setPosition(size.width/2, size.height/2);
this->addChild(p_StarOcean);
```

Xcode can compile and run it in my iPhone, but I see nothing in the screen.

From the book, it told me that the file created by PD2 should with *.plist naming format,  but what I created is *.pdproject format.

Any body could help to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi you need to export .plist from PD2. In the bottom of PD2 there are three buttons (Add System, Add Emitet, Export). Export it and load it to cocos2d-x. .pdproject file is the PD2 format to store the particle project.

Comment: Thank you sir. Your method works.

Comment: Np, let me see the result of your work.

Comment: Ahahah, I just start learn how to create game on iPhone, still have a long way to go. Will show you once I've done. But I don't know if I can walk till to the end. Maybe give up somewhere. Well, thank you again.